# jQuery Carousel not repeating

Tags: jquery, slideshow, jcarousel

I am trying to create a carousel for my site and am having trouble getting the slides to move to the back of the list, so it is a continuous stream with no white space. Here is the code:

```
<div class="maskleft"></div>
<div class="maskright"></div>

<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <div class="panel-text">text</div>  
        <div class="views-field views-field-field-image-feature">
            <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" alt="" />
        </div> 
        <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
        <div class="panel-text">text</div>  
        <div class="views-field views-field-field-image-feature">
            <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" alt="" />
        </div> 
        <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd">
        <div class="panel-text">text</div>  
        <div class="views-field views-field-field-image-feature">
            <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" alt="" />
        </div> 
        <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even views-row-last">
        <div class="panel-text">text</div>  
        <div class="views-field views-field-field-image-feature">
            <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" alt="" />
        </div> 
        <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery is:

```
function slideChange() {
    var $slider = $('.slideshow');

    var $next = $slider.next().length ? $slider.next() : $('.slideshow'); 

    $next.animate({marginLeft: '-=1024'}, 1000, function() {
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval( "slideChange()", 5000 );
});
```

The live dev site is here: http://dev.shoeboxdesign.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

1. You have only one `div` whitch is moving, why do you need this code:

   ```
   var $next = $slider.next().length ? $slider.next() : $('.slideshow');
   ```
2. You need to reset your `marginLeft` style when you reach end of your slideshow:

   ```
   if (... check the end of slideshow ...) { // could be calculation of the widht, count of slides, etc.
       $slider.css({marginLeft: '0'});
   }
   ```

Comment: I think he tries to do the following: Uppercase means visible. | A b c | A -> B c | a B c | a B -> C | a b C | b C -> A | A b c | and so on.

Your solution would jump back to the beginning without a nice transition.

Comment: No, I mean that he need to move back slider before nice transition and then perform animation. I didn't said to replace animation.

Comment: Yes, but when he moves back again there is a jump cut. There wouldn't be a transition from C to A. It would just reset the whole slide without an animation at all. But Chris wanted an continous stream of slides.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to append the first slide to the end of the slideshow so you have a constant stream instead of a jump cut back to the start.
Assuming this is correct, we found an important keyword: *append*.

You have to virtually take the first slide and append it to the last slide. Do this by every animation step. We end up with something like this.

```
function slideChange() {
    var $slider = $('.slideshow');
    var $first = $slider.first();

    $slider.append($first); // Append a copy of the first slide to the last one
    $slider.animate({marginLeft: '-=1024'}, 1000, function() {
        $first.remove(); // Remove the first slide we just copied. So we virtually swapped the slide from the first to the last place
        $slider.css({marginLeft: '+=1024'}); // Reset the margin
    });

}
```

This solution is untested but should do the trick.
But I still see some problems in your code.

Do you want to use this function *only for this* slider? If your answer is 'yes' you should definetly give your slider an `#id` and not a `.class` selector. And because you won't use your function anywhere again, there's no need for a publicly accessible function. You could make it anonymously, which saves some ressources.

```
setInterval(function() {
    /* Your stuff goes here */
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Hi, Yes I would like to add other functions to this, like sliding the main img down and hiding the non active bits

Comment: Is this correct?   'function slideChange() {
    var $slider = $('.slideshow');
    var $first = $slider.first();

    $slider.append($first); // Append a copy of the first slide to the    last one
    $slider.animate({marginLeft: '-=1024'}, 1000, function() {
        $first.remove(); // Remove the first slide we just copied. So     we virtually swapped the slide from the first to the last place
        $slider.css({marginLeft: '+=1024'}); // Reset the margin
    });

    }

    setInterval(function() {"slideChange()"}, 5000);)'

Comment: Would you be satisfied if your slider would work like this one? http://www.hybritalk.com/?page=info#slideshow (Takes some seconds to load. The images aren'nt compressed yet.)

Comment: Not really this does not scale the hole page.